# Using CSS3 @font-face in Grails web application

Tags: grails, css, font-face

Can anyone shed some clarity on how to use CSS3 @font-face styling in a Grails web application. How do I get the application to include the font in the war, and how do I reference it.

I'm fairly new to Grails, and I'm not sure where exactly to put the fonts so that they can be referenced in the CSS.

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

Seems that putting it in the `web-app` directory does not work. Example, let's say the font filename is `myfont.ttf`. I place it in the `web-app` directory and then in my css do:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myfont;
    src: url('myfont.ttf');
}
```

As far as I know that is correct, but it does not seem to work when I launch it from STS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a font embedding service like Google's free web fonts api (http://www.google.com/webfonts) then you don't need to put fonts in your app. You just grab the generated JS includes and the generated CSS, plonk it in and use it. Easy.

Comment: Well, I have the font I want to use. Will have a look at the Google web fonts though, maybe they have one I can use.

Comment: @Nico I'd prefer using a hosted font service like Google's if the font you need is there or even if there's one that is a close match.

Comment: OK, so that works perfectly! Thanks! I will see if I can find some fonts. I'm going to give someone a chance to answer my original question though, but if all else fails, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can put it into `web-app` dir, it's a place for all your static resources.

You can create directory like `web-app/fonts` and reference it as `/fonts/<you font>` (works only if you run your app in root context) or as `${resource(dir: 'fonts', file: '<your font>'}`

Comment: Does not seem to to the trick, please check my update, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: You are using relative path, and at your case, your font and css must be places in one directory. If you put your font in root of `web-app` and css in `css` dir, then you have to use `src: url('../myfont.ttf');` instead

Comment: Nope, still nothing. But I'm going with the hosted solution now, works flawlessly.

Comment: Nico, I suspect it's still a path issue here. Could you use firebug and see what the actual path that is being tried? If you use images in your CSS what paths are being used for them?